# Symbolic cut-off of high-order terms

Tags: replacement, polynomials

I know that I can cut-off high-order terms of a $1$-variable polynomial `P = a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2 + a3*x^3 + a4*x^4 + a5*x^5;` simply by doing for example `P /. {x^y_ /; y > 2 -> 0}`.

Now I have a $n$-variable polynomial expression and I want to cut off all the terms of order 3 and more, for every product of variables.

For example consider the polynomial `P = a*x^2 + b*x^3 + c*x*y + d*x^2*y + e*x*y^2 + y^2`, I want an operation who returns me `a*x^2 + c*x*y + y^2`

I am looking for a similar expression which does this cut-off for each symbol which is more than squared !

EDIT :

I didn't specify that I am considering a rational function. Mr.Wizard's answer works perfectly for the numerator, but what about the full function ?

Is it possible to do this cut-off for all the terms appearing in both the numerator and the denominator of a rational function ?

In general, the function I am considering is something like $(\sum a_i\prod x_j^i)/(\sum b_k\prod x_l^k)$ where the product is over the variables and the $a_i$ are the coefficients.

A simple example could be $(a_1x^2 + a_2xy^2z + a_3zy+a_4x )/(b_1y+b_2zy^2+b_3xz)$ which I want to cut-off to $(a_1x^2 + a_3zy+a_4x )/(b_1y+b_3xz)$

(Sorry I am not very clear in my questions...!)

Comment: Sorry for being obtuse but could you explain the transformation of `a*x^2 + b*x^3 + c*x*y + d*x^2*y + e*x*y^2 + y^2` into `a*x^2 + c*x*y + y^2` more literally?  I'm not seeing it. :-/

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  It appears that terms for which the sum of exponents in `x` and `y` exceeds two are being deleted.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks!  The text just didn't read that way to me but I think I see it now.

Comment: I still have a problem with the text; nowhere are `x` and `y` singled out as in bbgodfrey's observation.  However if I count the exponents of all variables in each term and add them the remaining ones are those with a total of three or less.  I posted an answer following that interpretation.

Comment: Use `Numerator[]` and `Denominator[]` to pick out those parts, do the cut-off on both, and recompose your new rational function.

Comment: You answered my question before I could even finish my edit, thank you too :)

Comment: @LSnoopyD I added a method to my answer.  If all `Plus` subexpressions in your expression are to be processed in this manner it should be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to bbgodfrey's comment I think I understand what you want:

```
p = a*x^2 + b*x^3 + c*x*y + d*x^2*y + e*x*y^2 + y^2;

Total @ Exponent[#, Variables @ #] & /@ List @@ p

Pick[P, # <= 3 & /@ %]
```

> ```
> {3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4}
>
> a x^2 + c x y + y^2
> ```

---

Following your update here is a somewhat different formulation that may be useful:

```
op[var_List, max_][p__] :=
  #*Boole[max >= Tr @ Exponent[#, var]] & /@ {p} // Total
```

Use is:

```
p = a*x^2 + b*x^3 + c*x*y + d*x^2*y + e*x*y^2 + y^2;

op[{x, y}, 2] @@ p       (* replace Plus using Apply *)
```

> ```
> a x^2 + c x y + y^2
> ```

Or:

```
p2 = (a1*x^2 + a2*x*y^2*z + a3*z*y + a4*x)/(b1*y + b2*z*y^2 + b3*x*z);

p2 /. Plus -> op[{x, y}, 2]        (* replace all instances of Plus *)
```

> ```
> (a4 x + a1 x^2 + a3 y z) / (b1 y + b3 x z + b2 y^2 z)
> ```

Comment: Thanks ! This looks perfect (you had the right interpretation, sorry if the question was fuzzy), but would you like to explain me what's going on here more precisely ?

Comment: (+1). I'd probably suggest one thing though. I think you'd have to specify what are the "non-coefficient" variables. So you're example would be... `Total @ Exponent[#, {x,y}] & /@ List @@ p` and then `Pick[P, # < 3 & /@ %]`, but we'd need further clarification from the OP on that regard...

Comment: @LSnoopyD I just updated the answer to a hopefully clearer form.  `List @@ p` splits the expression into a list of terms.  Then `Total @ Exponent[#, Variables @ #] &` is mapped over this list, which is a function to total the exponents of all variables in a given term.  Finally `Pick` is employed to select from `p` itself those totals which are <= 3, preserving the head of `p` which is `Plus`.  Hopefully this is the operation you wanted?

Comment: @kale I am uncertain of the correct interpretation, but thank you for providing a method for the other one too.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification. This is indeed what I wanted ! More precisely, the expression I want to cut-off isn't a polynomial but a rational function (I can replace `Variables @ P` by the list of variables generated at the beginning of my code), I hope this will not cause problems for this approach.

Comment: @LSnoopyD Please try it and see.  As you refer to the previous answer form know that you can view both version [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/86832/revisions).  Let me know if you run into problems.

Comment: It works perfectly for both the versions you posted. Thanks you very much :)

Comment: @LSnoopyD Glad I could help!

Answer (score 4):

Competely untested, but I believe this ought to work nicely:

```
p = a*x^2 + b*x^3 + c*x*y + d*x^2*y + e*x*y^2 + y^2;
coeffs = CoefficientArrays[p, {x, y}];
k = 2; (* highest degree wanted *)
Fold[#1.{x, y} + #2 &, {0, 0}, Take[coeffs, {k + 1, 1, -1}]]
```

Comment: I get `y^2 + x (a x + c y)` which is equivalent.  You're *too* good at programming blind!

Comment: `Expand[]` will take care of that, of course. :) Nevertheless, it's sometimes useful to leave polynomials in Horner form.

Answer (score 4):

Standard method: create a univariate in a new variable `t`, by changing every variable `x` to `t*x`. Take a `Series` expansion in `t`. Then use `Normal` to make it explicitly polynomial, and substitute `t->1`.

```
poly = a*x^2 + b*x^3 + c*x*y + d*x^2*y + e*x*y^2 + y^2;
vars = {x, y};
Normal[Series[poly /. Thread[vars -> t*vars], {t, 0, 2}]] /. t -> 1

(* Out[6]= a x^2 + c x y + y^2 *)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
P = a*x^2 + b*x^3 + c*x*y + d*x^2*y + e*x*y^2 + y^2 + f*x^2*y^3;

    rule1 = {Times[a_, Power[x, n_], y] -> n + 1, 
  Times[a_, x, Power[y, n_]] -> n + 1}
rule2 = Times[a_, Power[x, n_], Power[y, m_]] -> 
  m + n; rule3 = {Times[a_, Power[b_, n_]] -> n, Power[b_, n_] -> n, 
  Times[a_, x, y] -> 2};
rule3 = {Times[a_, Power[b_, n_]] -> n, Power[b_, n_] -> n, 
   Times[a_, x, y] -> 2};

Delete[P, 
 Position[(P /. Plus -> List) /. rule1 /. rule2 /. rule3, x_ /; x > 2]]

(*  a x^2 + c x y + y^2   *)
```